# Jasny bootstrap iconic icons in IE8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools, jasny-bootstrap

How can I use all those iconic icons in IE8 (http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#iconic)? Most of them seems not work in IE8...

Is this a bug in the Jansy plugin or just IE8 lacking?

Btw, if I open my internet explorer developer tools, I do see two errors in IE8 about @font-face.

Comment: Have you looked through the issues on that github repository? If you don't find it there, try posting a bug request. https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/issues

Answer (score 0):

After finding [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#examples) on the internet, I am certain it is a bug in the Jansy plugin as [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#examples) even works in IE7.